# How to Update Firebase Realtime Database a Specific Child Node/

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase Realtime Database structure:

[image]

I want to update `userProfilePic` in this structure.

I try my best but this is not being updated

here is my code

```
database.getReference()
    .child("User")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString())
    .child("userProfilePic")
    .setValue(uri)
    .addOnSuccessListener { 

    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,it.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Please tell me how I can update in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to `currentUser` when calling for `uid` like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid
```

Instead of:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to Update Firebase Realtime Database a Specific Child Node

If you want to perform an **update**, you should not be using setValue() but [updateChildren(Map<String, Object> update)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)), which:

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values.

Otherwise, you'll always overwrite the existing data. So to update the URL, please use the following lines of code:

```
val update = mapOf("userProfilePic" to uri) //
database.getReference()
    .child("User")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid) //
    .updateChildren(update)
    .addOnSuccessListener { 
        Toast.makeText(this,"Update successful.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,it.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: yes i have solved this by using this approach

Comment: Good to hear that, Muhammad.

Comment: it's my pleasure if you share knowledge with me

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding this question?

Comment: I was asking if I can help you with other information regarding this question "How to Update Firebase Realtime Database a Specific Child Node?", not in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider this snippet code

```
child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().toString())
```